# Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

i am trying to automate AAS models automation via ADF. I am passing dynamic values in Body field of web activity through lookup activity. And refresh value is the column name of my config table. Unable to remove it. Tried with "type": 1 and With proper casing as well(Full). Still sees same error, "message": "Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format.",

Tried with lookup activity for dynamic json values, as my list of partitions change every day based on a config table. We will produce final json through sql code and will store it in a column to be picked up using lookup activity.
But ended up getting below error:
{"code":"BadRequest","subCode":2,"message":"Request parameter RefreshType is not in correct format.","timeStamp":"2024-02-15T12:51:21.10585Z","httpStatusCode":400,"details":[{"code":"RootActivityId","message":"25f2d469-aae0-475c-8cdb-d79090e7fe73"},{"code":"Param1","message":"RefreshType"}]}

below is the input of web activity and i have problem with body field. Though i am not passing \ but seeing is multiple time in the ADF.

{
"method": "POST",
"headers": {},
"disableCertValidation": true,
"url": "https://test.asazure.windows.net/servers/test01/models/Self Service MI - Registrations/refreshes",
"connectVia": {
"referenceName": "test-selfhosted-ir-01",
"type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
},
"body": "{"refresh":"{\"type\":\"Full\",\"objects\":[{\"database\":\"Self Service MI - Registrations\",\"table\":\"Dim - Conferences\"},{\"database\":\"Self Service MI - Registrations\",\"table\":\"Dim - Boothscan\"},{\"database\":\"Self Service MI - Registrations\",\"table\":\"Dim - Tags\"},{\"database\":\"Self Service MI - Registrations\",\"table\":\"Dim - Sponsors\"}]}"}",
"authentication": {
"type": "MSI",
"resource": "https://*.asazure.windows.net"
}
}

Comment: can you add image of your pipeline for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

> Though I am not passing \ but seeing is multiple time in the ADF.

It is because as you are saying you are passing value from lookup to web activity boy it might consider Json as a string.

To remove that extra `\` from the body you need to enclose the value yore passing into `@json()` function as below example so it will not consider as a string.

[image]